# I am comparing two tables and want to get new rows from table which does not exist in old table

Tags: compare, peoplesoft

```
select * from New_tr 
where **(PeopleSoftID,** TransDate,TransactionCode)  not in 
(select PeopleSoftID,TransDate,TransactionCode from Old_tr)
```

It shows me the following error error:

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
```

What could be causing the error?

Comment: You cant use multiple columns while doing in or not in. is PeopleSoftId primary key?

Comment: Please put in some REAL sql that causes this error. I am able to do this type of query without a problem on Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 1):

I believe based on your error message you are using MS SQL Server.  MS SQL Server does not support multiple columns in an IN statement.  You can easily rewrite this as a left join  with a where is null to solve your issue

```
SELECT * FROM New_tr
LEFT JOIN Old_tr ON (Old_tr.PeopleSoftID = New_tr.PeopleSoftID 
                     and Old_tr.TransDate = New_tr.TransDate 
                     and Old_tr.TransactionCode = New_tr.TransactionCode)
where Old_tr.PeopleSoftID is null
```